# Mule hot deployement

Tags: mule, dynamic-loading, hotdeploy

I am working on a mule project where all my configurations are stored in a central repository, and at run-time am downloading the configuration and deploying it.

```
    <script:component doc:name="Script">
        <script:script engine="groovy">
          <![CDATA[
            String endpnt = reqUrl.prepareFile(requestUrl); 
            message.setProperty('endpnt', endpnt,org.mule.api.transport.PropertyScope.INVOCATION);
            message.setProperty('port', reqUrl.getPort(),org.mule.api.transport.PropertyScope.INVOCATION);      
          ]]>
        </script:script>
     </script:component>
```

The above script downloads the file and makes an entry in `mule-deploy.properties` against `config.resources`. I have already set `redeployment.enabled=true`, but still the endpoint is not available to consume, Please help

Comment: hot reload will not work for .properties, .resources and .java class files in mulesoft.

Answer (score 1):

Redeployment doesn't work on mule-deploy.properties, [here](https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-9596) is the ticket I reported for that.